# what is the meaning of the following expression in c++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

What is the meaning of the following expression in c++?

```
(variable1 | (variable2 << 8))
```

What is the meaning of it? And what does it represent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It concatenates the two variables.
Suppose you have two chars, `a` and `b`. `a|b<<8` shifts the `b` 8 bits to the left, `|` sets every bit that is in `a` or `b`.
So in this example the result would be "`ab`".

'a' is 97, 'b' is 98, so bitwise the following happens:

```
a:      01100001
b:              01100010
b<<8:   0110001000000000
a|b<<8: 0110001001100001
```

Comment: It does NOT "add" two variables!

Comment: @Nawaz You're right, but I'm not a native speaker so I hope you can forgive me ;)

Comment: @tstenner: You're forgiven. Removed -1.

Comment: Note that this is only concatenation when both variables are bytes!

Comment: the result is not "ab", the result is 12593 in bin, what you mean by "ab"?

Answer (score 7):

`|` is **[Bitwise OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx)**
`<<` is **[Bitwise left shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed.aspx)**

```
   (variable1 | (variable2 << 8))
```

Left Shifts the `variable2`(8 bit) by `8` and then `OR`s the result with `variable1`(8 bit), resulting output will combine two variables `variable1` and `variable2` to be represented as one variable(16 bit).

Answer (score 4):

You might think of it as "concatenating" two variables in a bitwise fashion.

If:

```
x = 00000000 00001000 (16-bit binary)
y = 00000000 00100010 (16-bit binary)
```

Then:

```
    (y << 8) = 00100010 00000000
x | (y << 8) = 00100010 00001000
```

What it actually *means* in the context of the code in which you found it is anybody's guess.

---

In actual fact, "concatenating" is not accurate if `x` has any bits set in the most significant byte:

If:

```
x = 01000000 00001000 (16-bit binary)
y = 00000000 00100010 (16-bit binary)
```

Then:

```
    (y << 8) = 00100010 00000000
x | (y << 8) = 01100010 00001000
```

Answer (score 1):

If `variable1` and `variable1` are 8-bit values, then it combines them into a single 16-bit value.

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense if both variables where bytes. In that case it would combine them into one larger variable, so that first come 8 bits of variable2 and then 8 bits of variable1.

Comment: Fixed that. It would probably make more sense to use `((variable2 << 8) | variable1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the 8 least significant (rightmost) bits of `variable1` are appended to the bits of `variable2` from the right, with the bits of `variable2` being shifted left by 8.

If denote the bits of `variable1` as

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwxxxxxxx
```

and the bits of `variable2` as

```
yyyyyyyyzyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

then expression

```
(variable1 | (variable2 << 8))
```

would result in

```
zyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyywxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "meaning" - but this is one variable being bitwise OR'ed with another variable which has been left-shifted by 8 bits (which you can think of as being multiplied by 256).

Answer (score 0):

If both `variable1` and `variable` are less than 256, the statement is the same as `variable1 + (variable2*256)`.

More generally though, `|` is binary or and and `<<` is left shift.

So if we start with:

```
variable1 = 321;
variable2 = 123;
```

The binary values would be:

```
variable1 =>  0000 0001 0100 0001
variable2 =>  0000 0000 0111 1011
```

Left shifting `variable2` by 8 results in:

```
              0111 1011 0000 0000
```

So `variable1 | (variable2 << 8)` equals

```
              0111 1011 0100 0001
```

Which is 32065.  This is less than 31519 which is the result of (321 + (123 * 256)) because `variable1` and `variable2 << 8` have some bits in common.